# "While != -1" -1 is erroneously appearing in my calculations (C#)

Tags: c#, while-loop

First, just want to say I'm grateful for this site; it's helped get me on the right track many times when I needed to debug.

I am VERY green with C#; I am an Intro to Programming student. I have written a program to calculate each person's parking charges and then do a grand total for all parking charges.  Following an example in the book, I set up a "While" loop to end only when the data entry person keys in "-1", otherwise, they are continuously asked to enter in another parking charge.

I was having trouble with getting the total charge for all and reached out to my professor.  He helped me resolve that problem but created another and didn't realize it.  I am reluctant to go back to the well a 2nd time, esp. to point out he created a new problem.  The issue is when you key in -1 to stop the loop, it returns back a total due.  It shouldn't do that, it's only there to stop the loop. Additionally, the total isn't even accurate; it is taking on the value of the prior entry (it's so odd that it feels like a big clue to me). Note that the loop DOES stop at this point so that is good; it just shouldn't also return a parking charge.

Below is most of the code (I omitted the initializations/declarations for the variables but can add if needed). I feel like the While and If statements should be preventing the "-1" from being calculated at all; can't figure out how it's "getting through":

```
  while (hoursParked != -1)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("Enter each customer's total hours parked (no more than 24) or type -1 to quit: ");
     hoursParked = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
     if (hoursParked > 0 && hoursParked < 3.0)
     {
        feeCharged = lessThan3Rate;
     }

     if (hoursParked >= 3.0 && hoursParked <= 18.00)
     {
        moreThan3thru18Rate = (2.00 + ((hoursParked - 2) * 0.50));
        feeCharged = moreThan3thru18Rate;

     if (hoursParked > 18.00)
     {
        feeCharged = moreThan18Rate; 
     }
     Console.WriteLine($"The customer's charge is: {feeCharged:C}");
     Console.WriteLine();

     totalAllReceipts = totalAllReceipts + feeCharged;//This will be the sum of all the fees charged. 
  }
  {
     Console.WriteLine("End of Day Totals:");
     Console.WriteLine($"The daily total of all receipts is: {totalAllReceipts:C}");
  }
```

I'm sure there are more efficient ways to perform the calculations and such but this is where we are in the class in terms of concepts so please ignore the remedial-level code!  TIA for any help!

Comment: what do you mean by "it returns a total due" which line of code is that?

Comment: SEarle1986, I'm not sure what line of code is driving that as a result of entering -1 (hence my question to this forum), but for every user entry that is 0 and above, the IF statements evaluate the user-entered value and return a total due ("feeCharged").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `while` condition is only evaluated at the top of the loop. So if you enter in -1, the rest of the lop is still executed. It then evaluated the `while` condition tand *then* exist, calculating the totals.

One option is to use `while(true)` instead, and break if the input is -1:

```
while (true)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Enter each customer's total hours parked (no more than 24) or type -1 to quit: ");
     hoursParked = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

     if(hoursParked == -1) break;

     if (hoursParked > 0 && hoursParked < 3.0)
     {
        feeCharged = lessThan3Rate;
     }
```

Comment: I'd probably go with a `do...while(hoursParked != -1)`,  but that's just because infinite loops bother me outside of embedded. Shrug - personal preference, I suppose.

Comment: @3Dave Feel free to add another answer, but `do..while` has basically the same mechanics and problem unless you grab console input both before the loop and within it.

Comment: D Stanley, this worked.  This is so confounding!  I followed the textbook as much as it made sense for my individual assignment's needs yet it didn't work.  Thank you for giving me a viable alternative.  This will be helpful in the future as well.  Grateful for your quick reply and thanks to all others!  :)

Comment: p.s. I voted this up but I don't have a high enough reputation score yet for it to show.

Answer (score 0):

Try 
if (hoursParked!=-1) 
     totalAllReceipts = totalAllReceipts + feeCharged;

Comment: Thank you. I changed the line of code per your suggestion (at the bottom where it currently exists) and it's still doing the same.  Should I make a change elsewhere?

Comment: } if (hoursParked > 18.00) change this(add { before if).you created a nest if by mistake